# Usage of gpgtar.exe on windows

Tags: encryption, gnupg

i want to use gpgtar.exe from command line to pack some files in a archive and then encrypt them using gpg.I am using gpg4win 2.3.1 on windows server 2008 R2 and since this process is automated from a SSIS package,i won't be able to use Kleopatra.

I have been searching for two days but have not found any syntax for gpgtar command. gpgtar --help is also not helpful.

I noticed that Kleopatra is successfully able to pack the file into an archive and its output window shows a command like

```
    gpgtar.exe --openpgp --skip-crypto --output........->A.tar.gpg
```

but its not completely visible (only (.) dots are shows)

May i request some help on this.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
I have already check the -h/--help option.

If I use -r with gpgtar then it says "invalid option r" although it is mentioned in the help text that we can use -r to specify a recipient.

Comment: Have you tried running `gpgtar -h` for usage information?

Comment: Additionally, yo0u can use process explorer (google it) to see the full command line.